# Set CNAME locally on OSX

Tags: macos, dns, cname

I am trying to get my Mac to resolve abc.com to xyz.com.

Tried in /private/etc/hosts:

```
abc.com xyz.com
```

and

```
abc.com in CNAME xyz.com
```

Neither works. Anyone know how to do this?

Comment: You probably want to add a local dns server to your computer, look into dnsmasq.

Answer (score 2):

Well, the hosts file is formatted as "IP_address hostname..." (as many hostnames as you need), so you *could* put the ip, followed by both abc.com and xyz.com.  It's not designed to work as a local CNAME.  It's a local resolver (think A record type action)...

Comment: I am trying to resolve an address on heroku, not sure if the ip address does not change...